# Ant-d Form validations in react form where both create and edit are done in same form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

I am using Ant-d Form Validations for  React Form in which both create and edit are done in same form which makes me lot of confusion on how to manage state in react do I need to apply getFieldDecorator for all fields and manage their state in form and How to setValues in this.props.form.Please help me of you can.If anything is wrong with question please help me to improve it.

```
 class OffersForm extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
      offer: this.props.offer,
    };
    this.handleSave= this.handleSave.bind(this);
    this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    if(!this.state.isNew){
    const offer = this.props.offer
    }
  }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.getOffers();
  }

  getOffers=() =>{
    if (this.props.offer) {
     this.setState({
       offer: this.props.offer
        }, () => {
       this.props.form.setFieldsValue(Object.assign({}, 
                                    this.props.offer));
         },()=>console.log("Props Values"+ getFieldsValue));
       }
      };

  handleOnChange(element, value) {
   const offer = Object.assign({}, this.state.offer, { [element]: 
                   value })

    this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
      offer
    }); 
    this.setState({ offer }) 
  }

  handleSave() {
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
    if (!err) {
      this.setState({ inProgress: true })
        } 
  } 

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;          
     return (
       <div>
         <Form>
           <Row gutter={16}>
             <Col xs={24} sm={24}>
               <Form.Item label={I18n.t('general.name')}>
                 { getFieldDecorator(
                    'name', {
                      initialValue:offer.name,
                      rules: [{required:true, message:'Please Enter 
                                Name'}],
                       })
                        ( <Input
                            value={offer.name}
                            onChange={e => 
                                      this.handleOnChange('name', 
                                       e.target.value)}
                            />)}
                  </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <div>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={12} sm={12}>
                  <Form.Item label={I18n.t('general.phone_number')}>
                    { getFieldDecorator('action_to', {
                       initialValue:offer.action_to,
                       rules: [{required:true, message: 'Please 
                                          Enter Phone Number'}],
                     })
                    (<Input
                        onChange={e => 
                        this.handleOnChange('action_to', 
                             e.target.value)}
                    />)}
                 </Form.Item>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
        <Row>
          {FormErrors(this.state.errors)}
        </Row>
         <Row>
           <Col span={24}>
              {FormButtons(this.state.inProgress, this.handleSave, 
                    this.props.onCancel)}
           </Col>
         </Row>
        </Form>
       </div>
       );
      }
      }
      export default Form.create()(OffersForm);
```

Errors

```
        Warning: You cannot set a form field before rendering a 
        field associated with the value.
```

Comment: Post a minimal example of your problem

Comment: Sorry for posting the full example as I don't know where did I went wrong in using form.I tried to reduce the unnecessary code.

Comment: what @DennisVash tried to say was "Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)", right? in any case, the error message you posted is clear, let me just format your question better..

Comment: well, the error message that you deleted was the clear one. the remaining warning is about `this.props.form.setFieldsValue` but that one is less clear to me, I don't see it called before rendering the field...

Comment: `FormButtons` isn't part of https://ant.design/components, can it call the function from its second argument before rendering?

Comment: There is no issue with FormButtons.It is just a component which is reused in every form in application

Comment: there should be a line associated with the warning, can you copy the line here please?

Comment: @Aprillion I found where I did wrong in my code, I'm setting the form values using onChange function which is not needed when we are using ant-d form.Form values set into this.props.form by default.Thanks for Guiding me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning that you removed from your question:

> Warning: `getFieldDecorator` will override `value`, so 
>           please don't set `value` directly and use `setFieldsValue` 
>           to set it.

is about following part of the code:

```
           <Form.Item...
             { getFieldDecorator(
                    ( <Input
                        value={offer.name}
                        ...
```

And can be fixed by removing the `value={offer.name}` part.

Comment: Really,Thank you so much for your help I got the point.Can  you please help me the Warning: You cannot set a form field before rendering a  field associated with the value

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of onChange function for setting values in this.props.form.This 
   is the cause of the warning

Warning: You cannot set a form field before rendering a field associated with 
   the value.

```
   <Row>
    <Col>
     <Form.Item label={I18n.t('general.email')}>
              { getFieldDecorator('action_to', {
                 rules: [
                   {type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!'},
                   {required:true, message: 'Please Enter Email'}],
                })
                (<Input/>)
              }
      </Form.Item>
     </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row>
     <Col>
      <Form.Item label={I18n.t('general.name')}>
          { getFieldDecorator('name', {
            rules: [{required:false, message:'Please Enter Name'}],
            })
            (<Input />)
          }
       </Form.Item>
     </Col>
   </Row>
```

we can get the values of this.props.form using getFieldsValue()
const formData = this.props.form.getFieldsValue();